# Java SSL provider needed for HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I'm trying to rid our old code of these System/Security statements:

```
System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
```

If I have code that casts an https `URLConnection` to an `HttpUrlConnection`, is that security stuff even used? In other words, would anything change if I removed the `System.setProperty(...` and `Security.addProvider(...` lines?

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

The code is currently running on Java 1.5 (soon to be updated to Java 8), and I think the code was written back when it was running Java 1.3.

Comment: Yes, you can get rid of those statements.  https connections work out of the box (assuming you don't have special certificate needs).